# Unable to access images stored inside my App_Data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

I have the following link inside my asp.net mvc web application :-

```
<a href="~/App_Data/uploads/38.png">@Model.Name</a>
```

But when I click on this link, I get the following error :

> HTTP Error 404.8 - Not Found
>
> The request filtering module is configured to deny a path in the URL that contains a hiddenSegment section.

So what is causing this problem , and how I can solve it ?

Thanks

Comment: IIS7 thinks you're trying to serve up your app internals; see http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments and http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments. If you have to save your uploaded png files there, then create a virtual directory pointing towards `~/App_Data/uploads/` and serve it as e.g. `~/uploads/`. Otherwise, I'd just put your png files somewhere else than `App_Data`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Controller (e.g. "Streamer") and Action (e.g. "StreamUploadedImage") that streams the image (the Action will typically return a FileResult).

Change the url to reference your action, passing the image id as a parameter, e.g. (from memory so syntax may not be accurate):

```
@Html.ActionLink(Model.Name, "StreamUploadedImage", "Streamer", new {id = "38" })
```

An alternative would be to put the uploaded image in a location where it can be accessed from the client, e.g. in a subfolder of the Content folder:

```
<a href="~/Content/uploads/38.png">@Model.Name</a>
```

But using a controller gives you more control, e.g. to implement authorization.

Answer (score 1):

The path is blocked by your IIS. To resolve, move the files to an other location ("~/Uploads/Images/" perhaps?).

The reason why IIS is blocking some folders is beacause they can contain importent data or files, which the user should not have access to. To avoid hackers from getting this information, the IIS is denying access to any of the files in those folders.

For more information: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/hiddensegments