# Displaying images Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone I am trying to display all the images I have in a folder and I get this error nullreference exception Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when it gets to Model.Images, i put a break point on the foreach line and the model is empty even though there is images in the folder, any idea how to fix this?

Thanks for any help with this issue.

controller

```
 public ActionResult Getimages()
    {
        var model = new imagesModel()
        {
            Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Img"))
                              .Select(fn => "~/Img" + Path.GetFileName(fn))
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

model

```
 public class imagesModel
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Images { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model MyProject.Models.imagesModel

@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
<img src = "@Url.Content(image)" alt = "image" />
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model MyProject.Models.imagesModel



@foreach (var image in Model.Images)
{
<img src = "@Url.Content(image)" alt = "image" />
}
```

Comment: Hi Hristo, it now seems to get a" 
nullreference exception Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when it gets to Model.Images, i put a break point on the foreach line and the model is empty even though there is images in the folder, any idea how to fix this?  thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to ass ToLost();
So 1. `return View(model).ToList();`
Or 2.

```
    Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"))
                                  .Select(fn => "~/App_Data" + 

Path.GetFileName(fn).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Assaf, I get  does not contain definition error when i write "return View(model).ToList();" and I get the same error as previously(null exception) when I write:  " public ActionResult Getimages()
        {
            var model = new imagesModel()
            {
                Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"))
                                  .Select(fn => "~/App_Data" + Path.GetFileName(fn).ToList())
            };
            return View(model);
        } "  any other ideas and thanks for helping (also just out of curiosity did that work for you)

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring the images from App_data folder. well, it will not work because HttpRequest doesn't goes inside the App_data folder. it's restricted folder.

[Unable to access images stored inside my App_Data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928301/unable-to-access-images-stored-inside-my-app-data-folder)

Make sure your app_data does have some images. maybe its' have no images that's  why it's not working.

Comment: Hi Gupta, When I first created this i was trying to access the App_Data folder but found out that it could be an issue and swapped to a folder called Img but I still get this null ref exception and i have jpgs in both an app_data and img folder currently but no success thanks for trying to help any other ideas? (also if you have tried the code and it works your end let me know and thanks again )

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot to insert `/` in path.

Insert

```
Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Img"))
                  .Select(fn => "~/Img/" + Path.GetFileName(fn))
```

in place of

```
Images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Img"))
                  .Select(fn => "~/Img" + Path.GetFileName(fn))
```

And I have `Img` folder in here:

[image]